# How to remove extra backslashes from my json result in karate?

Tags: json, karate, xls

I'm reading an xls file in java and I'm converting that xls file data into a Hashmap. I'm returning this hashmap to the feature file. But i'm getting output something like this.

```
{
 "names": [
   "{\"color\":\"blue\",\"name\":\"sushma\",\"id\":\"1\"}",
   "{\"color\":\"orange\",\"name\":\"divya\",\"id\":\"2\"}",
   "{\"color\":\"pink\",\"name\":\"lohi\",\"id\":\"3\"}"
 ]
}
```

where names is the sheet name and the remaining is data of the sheet.

```
* json results = doTesting.readExcel("C:\\Users\\sushma.i.dangeti\\eclipse-workspace\\xls\\ReadingxlsDemo.xls", "names")
```

Instead of using def, I have used json in the feature file but it is also not working. And also if I'm trying to access for instance, results.names[0].color then Its not printing anything.
Can someone help me with this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you got JSON from an external source, you need to take care of conversions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

Here's a tip, this should convert the JSON you provided in your question. Try it and see.

```
* def raw =
"""
{
 "names": [
   "{\"color\":\"blue\",\"name\":\"sushma\",\"id\":\"1\"}",
   "{\"color\":\"orange\",\"name\":\"divya\",\"id\":\"2\"}",
   "{\"color\":\"pink\",\"name\":\"lohi\",\"id\":\"3\"}"
 ]
}
"""
* def fun = function(x){ return karate.fromString(x) }
* raw.names = karate.map(raw.names, fun)
* print raw
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I have tried the above code snippet, but I'm getting the output like this: {
  "names": [
    [type: JSON, value: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext@c7db3a],
    [type: JSON, value: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext@1d67a42],
    [type: JSON, value: com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext@16ac636]
  ]}. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @SushmaIndrani time for you to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue